# Validate User Input, check if input is positive number and not string of characters

Tags: java, validation, input

I'm trying to write a program that can validate user's input before going to the next section, but i'm currently stuck with this. Whenever i enter a negative value first, it will bypass the condition or crashes.

If i input "A" , it will show "Please enter a valid number"

If i input "-1", it will show "Please enter a positive number"

But soon after i enter -1, if I input another negative value, it by pass the condition and accept the negative value, while input character will crashed the program.

What i want to achieve here to have a program that can

Check whether Input is number and not letter or string, and check if it's positive number

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int Users = 0;
  boolean isNumber;
  System.out.print("Enter the number of Users ");
  do {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
      Users = input.nextInt();
      isNumber = true;
      if (Users < 0) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number ");
        Users = input.nextInt();
      }
    } else {
      System.out.print("Please enter a valid number ");
      isNumber = false;
      input.next();
    }
  } while (!(isNumber));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `isNumber` to `False` if it's less than 0. This means that, if you ever enter a negative value (and you haven't entered a string before), your program will ask you for another number again and it won't check if it's negative as `isNumber` will be `True`, meaning that the `while` loop will no longer run.

To fix this, add `isNumber = False;` to the end of the `if (Users<0){` code block.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with your code.  The first one is that `isNumber` is being set to true even if the input is a negative number, so I would recommend only setting it to true after you've verified that it's not negative.

The second problem is that in your `if (Users < ) { ... }` block, you're getting `input.nextInt()`.  You should really just go to the next iteration of the do-while loop and get the next input on the next iteration.

Third, you should initialize `isNumber` to `false`;

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int Users = 0;
  boolean isNumber = false;
  System.out.print("Enter the number of Users ");
  do {
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
      Users = input.nextInt();
      if (Users < 0) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive number ");
        // Remove this line:
        // Users = input.nextInt();
      } else {
        // Moved this to an else block:
        isNumber = true;
      }
    } else {
      System.out.print("Please enter a valid number ");
      // remove this because it's already initialized to false:
      // isNumber = false;
      input.next();
    }
  } while (!(isNumber));
}
```